# How can I fix type error 'int' object is not iterable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to make a program where I can use a function seperate from the main function to take the list from the main function and put it into descending order and then return the list, however, this is the error I keep getting:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#41>", line 1, in <module>
    main()
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 7, in main
    print(change_list(number)[i:i+9])
  File "<pyshell#40>", line 2, in change_list
    list1 = sorted(number)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

This is the program I used:

```
import random
def main():
    list1 = []
    for count in range(100):
        number = random.randint(1,100)
        list1.append(number)
    for i in range(0,100,10):
        print(change_list(number)[i:i+9])
        print(dir(number))

        
def change_list(number):
    list1 = sorted(number)
    return list1

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are passing a single integer number to the change_list() function instead of the list named list1 that you want to sort.

Here's the corrected code:

```
import random

def main():
    list1 = []
    for count in range(100):
        number = random.randint(1,100)
        list1.append(number)
    for i in range(0,100,10):
        print(change_list(list1)[i:i+10])
        
def change_list(list1):
    list1 = sorted(list1, reverse=True)
    return list1

main()
```

Also, I removed the `print(dir(number))` line as it messes up the output.

The above code would call the change_list function 10 times, which is not necessary as it is doing the same thing everytime, so I assume you wanted the big list of 100 elements to be divided into lists of 10 elements and sorted individually, to do this you can change the `print(change_list(list1)[i:i+10])` to `print(change_list(list1[i:i+10]))`.

Here's the code:

```
import random

def main():
    list1 = []
    for count in range(100):
        number = random.randint(1,100)
        list1.append(number)
    for i in range(0,100,10):
        print(change_list(list1[i:i+10]))
        
def change_list(list1):
    list1 = sorted(list1, reverse=True)
    return list1

main()
```